# Update all occurence of String in File using Java

Tags: java, file

I have 1 file, which contains some String that need to be updated.

```
MY REPORT
REPORT RUN DATE : 27/08/2012 12:35:11 PAGE 1 of @TOTAL@                                              
SUCCESSFUL AND UNSUCCESSFUL DAILY TRANSACTIONS REPORT                                                                                    
---record of data here----

MY REPORT                                                                                                                                                 
REPORT RUN DATE : 27/08/2012 12:35:11 PAGE 2 of @TOTAL@                                              
SUCCESSFUL AND UNSUCCESSFUL DAILY TRANSACTIONS REPORT
---record of data here----
```

In case I just want to update all occurence of @TOTAL@ to some number, is there a quick and effecient way to do this?

I understand that I can also use BufferedReader+BufferedWriter to print to another file and use String.replace it along the way, but I wonder if there is a better and elegant way to solve this...

The file wont exceed 10MB, so there is no need to concern whether the file can be to big ( exceed 1 GB etc )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I wonder if there is a better and elegant way to solve this

It depends on what you mean by "better and elegant", but IMO the answer is no.

> The file wont exceed 10MB, so there is no need to concern whether the file can be to big ( exceed 1 GB etc )

You are unlikely to exceed 1Gb.  However:

- You probably cannot be 100% sure that the file won't be bigger that 10Mb.  For any program that has a significant life-time, you can rarely know that the requirements and usage patterns won't change over time.
- In fact, a 10Mb text file may occupy up to 60Mb of memory if you load the entire lot into a StringBuilder.  Firstly, the bytes are inflated into characters.  Secondly, the algorithm used by StringBuilder to manage its backing array involves allocating a new array of double the size the original one.  So peak memory usage could be up to 6 times the number of bytes in the file you are reading.
- Note that 60Mb is greater than the default maximum heap size for some JVMs on some platforms.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the file being too large, and think calling `replace()` on every line is inelegant, I guess you can just read the entire file into a single String, call `replace()` once, then write it to the file.

Comment: However I have to cater the alignment of the records between each page.

Comment: @Rudy don't know what you mean about alignment, does that have to do with the "some number"?